# Why do Allah swear by Himself in Qur'an 70:40?

Tags: tafseer, oaths, surat-al-maarij

I have question concerning surah ([70:40](http://quran.com/70/40)).

> So I swear by the Lord of [all] risings and settings that indeed We are able ...

Does Allah (swt) swear by Himself? Is there any particular reason? Wassalam.

Answer (score 1):

The point in this verse is representation of the Mashariq and Magharib divinity, Which is In fact, shows the power of Allah, In order to make the people understand by this Causality who manages all the events and leading the world is up to him and no events harass him and won’t prevent him to create other events, because all events are his actions. Therefore no creatures of him won't prevent him to create. And Allah is the one god who has no partner in divinity.

Ref.: [Al-Mizan](http://www.wofis.com/Publications.aspx?bookID=8&partID=42)